# How do I calculate principal quantum numbers of the Lyman series

Tags: quantum-chemistry

How do I calculate principal quantum numbers of the Lyman series?

I've been given that the lowest line is 121.6nm and the 5th line is 93.8nm

The formula of the wavenumber is   v=-R(1/n2^2 - 1/n1^2)

My taught was that as the wavenumber is known (1/wavelength) I could create an equation

v/-R = 1/(x+4)^2 - 1/x^2   and solve for x to get the principal quantum numbers

However this equation seems to be too hard to solve and I guess there is a different way to solve this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's not a "good" answer, but since $n_1$ and $n_2$ are both small positive integers, trial and error works pretty well.

Comment: Lyman series, by definition, is a series with $n_2=1$, so you have to find just the $n_1$, which is not that hard.